# Update values in Mysql timestamp to a datetime value.

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I need to Update values in Mysql timestamp filed to a datetime value. for example for a field join date, currently the field type is int(11) and the values are in timestamp. I need change this fields as date time filed or create a new datetime filed , then populate the field with datetime value of old timestamp value.

It can do with php code with looping . If there is any mysql query for that it will be interesting.

Many thanks for all of your helps,
Happy coding

Comment: for mysql datetime insertion  `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, alter the table by adding another column of field `DateTime`. Name this column as `DateTimeField` or whatever you want. After the table has been altered, execute this query

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    DateTimeField = FROM_UNIXTIME(yourOldTimstampField)
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick responce, I iwll check it now

Comment: Alternatively you can change your current Unix Timestamp field to a VARCHAR(50), run the update code above (but using the same field names), and then change the column again to a DateTime field. Saves having to create another column.

Answer (score 2):

1st add a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable 
  ADD COLUMN new_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '2013-01-08 00:00:00' AFTER preceding_col
```

Then update:

```
UPDATE youTable SET new_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(old_date)
```

and after that you can drop the old column (if needed):

```
Alter TABLE yourTable drop column old_date;
```