# Update value in field to timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

i have database 
then i have table (post) have field (time_post)
the old value in time_post real number like (1443191344)
I want update to formula (0000-00-00 00:00:00)
i know should use this method FROM_UNIXTIME() in my command

## But I don't have right way to command in MySqL

note :

## 1443191344 to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

thanks

Comment: You need to add new column of the datetime type (the current one is int?) and then do the update to set the value of new column by `FROM_UNIXTIME()`

Comment: the current is varchar .
can u gave me the command for update values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14208565

Comment: thank u bro, that work with me